# Update customer user details excluding password in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a form where a customer user's information can be updated by an admin. I do not want the admin to be able to change the customer's password so I use a hidden field to store the password. This is unsafe as the password can be see in the page source.

What is the best practice to avoided this? Should I store the `UserDto` or password field in the controller and update it after it's returned? I have also see people request the entity again in the service and update it there with the modified fields.

File `customer-form.jsp`

```xml
<form:form action="saveCustomer" modelAttribute="customer" method="POST">
    <form:hidden path="id"/>
    <form:hidden path="username"/>
    <form:hidden path="password"/>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
        <form:input path="firstName" class="form-control" id="firstName"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
        <form:input path="lastName" class="form-control" id="firstName"/>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onClick="window.location.href='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/employee/customer/list'">Cancel</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onClick="deleteCustomer()">Delete</button>
</form:form>
```

File `CustomerController.java`

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/employee/customer")
public class CustomerController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    
    @RequestMapping("showFormForUpdate")
    public String showFormForUpdate(@ModelAttribute("userId")Long id,
                                    Model customerModel) {
        UserDto userDto = userService.getUser(id);
        customerModel.addAttribute("customer", userDto);
        return "employee/customer-form";
    }

    @PostMapping("/saveCustomer")
    public String saveCustomer(@ModelAttribute("customer")CustomerDto customer) {
        userService.saveUser(customer);
        return "redirect:list";
    }
}
```

Comment: On save, re-read the customer from `userService`, then merge in the fields that should be changed and save the result.

Comment: Let's show your model `CustomerDto` , `UserDto`

Comment: facing the same issue. were you able to resolve it?